# How to produce the first, second and third modes of vibration in a timpani

Tags: frequency, vibrations

For a timpani, when hitting it in the center, how do you produce first, second and third modes of vibration? Second mode has a higher frequency than the first, does that imply do you hit the timpani harder?

Comment: *Do* people control the mode when striking in the center? Being at once a physicist and not a percussionist, if someone had asked me out of the blue how to select the mode of a drum expressed after striking it, I would have said "By *where* you hit it". It's not at all obvious to me that you could be selective when striking in the center.

Comment: Ohhh ... a comment in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/219605/520) to an earlier questions may be relevant: *"it is the sound of a tuned membranophone such as timpani. But in [that] case, the audible tone is produced mainly by oscillations of air volume inside the drum."* which put a whole different set of physics in the picture. Interesting.

Comment: Hitting the exact center of a timpani drum is a horrible place to try and get a good sound from it. But in general the different modes for circular membranes are complicated and involve Bessel functions. I do not have time to get into it, but maybe someone else will. The problem is that hitting the drum will not produce just one mode, just like how plucking a guitar string does not result in just one frequency of vibration.

Comment: @dmckee I'm not sure if people do control mode. I'm currently researching for a maths assignment which revolves around graphing the different modes of vibration. If you hit it at different places, they have their own sets of modes.  Refer to this website: http://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/demos/membranecircle/circle.html

Comment: @AaronStevens thanks for proving my point :D, I'm currently doing something around Bessel function and discussing about how hitting it in the centre is terrible. However, I tried to add more to paper by talking about the different modes of vibration. However, I am still confused how does one control modes of vibration :( I assumed that they just hit the drum with higher force, thus creating a higher frequency but I'm worried that this is not the case.

Comment: With timpani drums the main pitch of the drum is controlled by a pedal that actually changes the tension in the drum head.

Comment: You should be very clear with whether you mean actual real-world timpani or just the idealized version embodied by a vibrating membrane with a fixed boundary. Real-world timpani are sealed enclosures, which means that the damping is very different for the fundamental and the azimuthally-excited states (because the latter conserve the cavity volume while the former doesn't). You know, that kind of pesky stuff ;-).

Answer (score 1):

If you hit in the exact center, then all of the modes involved will be axisymmetric. Hitting the drum creates an initial deformation. That deformation can then be resolved into a superposition of normal modes. That is, the set of deformations can be thought of as a vector space, with the normal modes as a basis. Modes beyond the first one are excited by the initial deformation not being exactly in the "direction" of the first mode; that is, it's not the the space spanned by the first mode. Note that each mode is an eigenvector of the operator describing wave evolution, and thus the "first mode" is unique only up to scalar multiples. So "direction" here is not referring to physical direction, but being a scalar multiple of whatever representative eigenvector  you take for the first eigenvalue.

That is, if your initial hit does not match a scaled version of the first mode, then it will involve other modes, with those modes adding together to create your initial deformation.

Seeing as how it's pretty much impossible to exactly replicate the first mode simply by hitting the drum, any hit will excite modes beyond the first. The first mode involves deformation throughout the drum, while a hit will be highly localized, so you have to have infinitely many modes, with the modes reinforcing in the center of the drum where you hit it, but canceling out everywhere else. It's basically like getting the Fourier transform of a spike, if that means anything to you. Hitting harder will create more of a spike, so I believe that will require more of the further modes.

In practice, it's even more complicated, since you won't be hitting the exact center of the drum, and therefore will be exciting nonaxisymmetric modes as well.

Comment: This is a good explanation! Another point to be made in reference to the question, in this case you cannot really label different modes as "second" or "third", since there is not a unique ordering of modes like you have on say a guitar string.

Comment: @AaronStevens According to [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibrations_of_a_circular_membrane](wikipedia), modes can be characterized by two parameters, with one of the parameters being zero for axisymmetric modes, so there is a canonical ordering if you hit in the exact center.

Comment: This is true. I was just thinking in more general terms with respect to the title. Thanks!

Comment: @Acccumulation That's what I was thinking as well. I think I will have to set some conditions within my paper so that it matches up with the conditions you said. Just to clarify, "Hitting harder will create more of a spike, so I believe that will require more of the further modes" does that imply that hitting harder can potentially change the modes? Sorry for being ignorant, I don't do physics nor music, however, this was one of the topics that intrigued me.

Comment: This isn't quite accurate. Timpani are sealed enclosures, which means that any modes that alter the cavity volume (i.e. primarily the fundamental, but also most/all axisymmetric modes) are strongly damped, and the design is often chosen to accentuate this feature.